# Build Windows image for openstack with packer

Tags: windows, packer, openstack

I am trying to build Windows image for Openstack with packer, but i don't know how to add the autounattend.xml file or floppy files.

I build the image with success from qemu but I cannot find the same for openstack.

For Qemu i have the floppy_files for virtio-win drives and the autounattend that is automate the installation. How i can parse the files to openstack for automation?

Comment: Were you able to solve it eventually @pioupiou?